# How to portably extend a file accessed using mmap()

Tags: linux, macos, mmap

We're experimenting with changing SQLite, an embedded database system,
to use mmap() instead of the usual read() and write() calls to access
the database file on disk. Using a single large mapping for the entire
file. Assume that the file is small enough that we have no trouble
finding space for this in virtual memory.

So far so good. In many cases using mmap() seems to be a little faster 
than read() and write(). And in some cases much faster.

Resizing the mapping in order to commit a write-transaction that 
extends the database file seems to be a problem. In order to extend
the database file, the code could do something like this:

```
  ftruncate();    // extend the database file on disk 
  munmap();       // unmap the current mapping (it's now too small)
  mmap();         // create a new, larger, mapping
```

then copy the new data into the end of the new memory mapping.
However, the munmap/mmap is undesirable as it means the next time each 
page of the database file is accessed a minor page fault occurs and
the system has to search the OS page cache for the correct frame to
associate with the virtual memory address. In other words, it slows
down subsequent database reads.

On Linux, we can use the non-standard mremap() system call instead
of munmap()/mmap() to resize the mapping. This seems to avoid the
minor page faults.

QUESTION: How should this be dealt with on other systems, like OSX, 
that do not have mremap()?

---

We have two ideas at present. And a question regarding each:

1) Create mappings larger than the database file. Then, when extending
   the database file, simply call ftruncate() to extend the file on
   disk and continue using the same mapping.

This would be ideal, and seems to work in practice. However, we're
   worried about this warning in the man page:

"The effect  of  changing  the  size  of the underlying file of a 
   mapping on the pages that correspond to added or removed regions of
   the file is unspecified."

QUESTION: Is this something we should be worried about? Or an anachronism 
   at this point?

2) When extending the database file, use the first argument to mmap()
   to request a mapping corresponding to the new pages of the database
   file located immediately after the current mapping in virtual
   memory. Effectively extending the initial mapping. If the system
   can't honour the request to place the new mapping immediately after
   the first, fall back to munmap/mmap.

In practice, we've found that OSX is pretty good about positioning
   mappings in this way, so this trick works there.

QUESTION: if the system does allocate the second mapping immediately
   following the first in virtual memory, is it then safe to eventually
   unmap them both using a single big call to munmap()?

Comment: I've been doing exactly the same thing. On Solaris 10 `munmap` does a synchronous `msync` if I remember correctly. In fact `msync` was always synchronous on Solaris 10 even when `MS_ASYNC` was specified. These were a couple of the last nails in Solaris coffin.

Comment: I don't think #1 is feasible. Creating a mapping larger than the file results in the tail end of the file not being accessible (although it may be "mapped"), and `ftruncate()` won't update the mapping.

Answer (score 9):

2 will work but you don't have to rely on the OS happening to have space available, you can reserve your address space beforehand so your fixed mmapings will always succeed.

For instance, To reserve one gigabyte of address space. Do a

`mmap(NULL, 1U << 30, PROT_NONE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);`

Which will reserve one gigabyte of continuous address space without actually allocating any memory or resources. You can then perform future mmapings over this space and they will succeed. So mmap the file into the beginning of the space returned, then mmap further sections of the file as needed using the fixed flag. The mmaps will succeed because your address space is already allocated and reserved by you.

Note: linux also has the MAP_NORESERVE flag which is the behavior you would want for the initial mapping if you were allocating RAM, but in my testing it is ignored as PROT_NONE is sufficient to say you don't want any resources allocated yet.

Comment: how should we handle the last page in case the file size is not aligned to the page size? In case we need to grow the mapping, should we remap the last page and start from there?

Comment: You can do that if you want, you would map your whole file in anyway including the last page and whatever excess space you want, if you map it writable you can change just part of the page and it should just work. You can call ftruncate to chop off anything extra if the os rounded your file size up.

Answer (score 5):

1. Use fallocate() instead of ftruncate() where available. If not, just open file in O_APPEND mode and increase file by writing some amount of zeroes. This greatly reduce fragmentation.
2. Use "Huge pages" if available - this greatly reduce overhead on big mappings.
3. pread()/pwrite()/pwritev()/preadv() with not-so-small block size is not slow really. Much faster than IO can actually be performed.
4. IO errors when using mmap() will generate just segfault instead of EIO or so.
5. The most of SQLite WRITE performance problems is concentrated in good transactional use (i.e. you should debug when COMMIT actually performed).

Comment: Using `fallocate()` defeats delayed allocation, forcing disk seeks and metadata updates to allocate physical blocks for the new file region immediately, rather than allowing allocation to occur when the dirtied pages are later flushed. In fact, using `fallocate()` can *worsen* fragmentation if multiple files are being extended concurrently: you'll end up with their blocks interleaved on disk. Generally, you should only use `fallocate()` to preallocate a large file whose size you know in advance (such as a file to be copied or downloaded).

Comment: @Matt Whitlock: your comment is basically wrong on all accounts - fallocate does not defeat delayed allocation in any way, does not force disk seeks or metadata updates or does anything more immediatelly than other forms of I/O. All it does is allocate space in advance, which typically reduces fragmentation, and never increases it unless fallocate is called more often then writing to the map. fallocate also doesn't worsen fragmentation over writes - it's basically always a win.

Comment: @MarcLehmann: Unfortunately you're incorrect on all accounts. Try it if you don't believe me. `rm -f {del,pre}alloc && dd if=/dev/zero of=delalloc bs=16M count=1 && fallocate -l$((16<<20)) prealloc && dd if=/dev/zero of=prealloc bs=16M count=1 conv=notrunc && filefrag -v {del,pre}alloc` You will see that the `delalloc` file shows `unknown_loc,delalloc` on its extent whereas the `prealloc` file immediately has a physical offset on disk. Finding a physical location for the extent requires accessing the free-space B-tree on disk. For fun, do a `sync` and then run the `filefrag` command again. ;)

Comment: @MarcLehmann: fallocate also does worsen external fragmentation. If you write several files of various sizes and you fallocate each before writing it, then the file system must immediately choose where to place each file individually, and it will often put each into a space that is just big enough to hold it. If, however, you omit the fallocate calls, then the file system is free to allocate and flush all of the files in one big contiguous chunk, which is, of course, beneficial later when you're reading those files as a group.

Comment: @MattWhitlock Your test is invalid, you can't compare the fallocate binary with the fallocate systcll. The fallocate binary allocate then fsync and close the file, forcing an immediate write of metadata and data! Also dd used to fsync the file at the end but no longer do apparently. Try adding `conv=fsync` to your first dd and you'll actually see different results - both will be allocated on disk.

Comment: @MattWhitlock Also delalloc and fallocate both achieve the same role, so it doesn't matter delalloc isn't compatible with fallocate, either one serve the same purpose. Delayed allocation lets you write more data before blocks are allocated, allowing the file system to find a suitable extend to allocate the file and prevent fragmentation. fallocate does the same thing, but upfront, so that you have no risk of getting `ENOSPC` during the write. It will also allow allocating blocks beyond the dirty data high watermark / 30s sync delay.

Answer (score 4):

1. I think #2 is the best currently available solution. In addition to this, on 64bit systems you may create your mapping explicitly at an address that OS would never choose for an mapping (for example 0x6000 0000 0000 0000 in Linux) to avoid the case that OS cannot place the new mapping immediatly after the first one.
2. It is always safe to unmap mutiple mappinsg with a single munmap call. You can even unmap a part of the mapping if you wish to do so.

Comment: most real-world 64 bit implementations (i.e. actual cpus) do not support 64 bit address spaces. for example, none of the existing amd64 cpus support the 0x6000 0000 0000 0000 address.